# kv root variables are not accessable in python

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

This is my kv file where i created a custom widget and two root variable name and date in kv itself.

```
<Entry@Widget>:
    name: ''
    date: ''
    size_hint: (None, None)
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, .4
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
    Label:
        text: root.name[0:1]
        color: 41/255, 128/255, 185/255, 1
        pos: root.pos
        font_size: sp(50)
    Label:
        text: root.name[1:]
        color: 41/255, 128/255, 185/255, 1
        pos: root.x+sp(80), root.y+sp(8)
        font_size: sp(30)
    Label:
        text: root.date
        color: 17/255, 80/255, 122/255, 1
        pos: root.x+sp(50), root.y-sp(10)
        font_size: 10
```

And there is one more thing. I ovveride on_touch_down event of Entry widget like below in python code:

```
class Entry(RelativeLayout):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        super(Entry, self).on_touch_down(touch)
        popup = Mypopup()
        popup.open()
        return True
```

Now in my main screen i am dynamically adding widgets so i had i type code in python which seems like below:-

```
class MainScreen(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kargs)
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
        for i in range(100):
            entry = Entry(name='Facebook', date='30/21/2', size=(Window.width, sp(100)))
            layout.add_widget(entry)    
        scroll = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), height=Window.height)
        scroll.add_widget(layout)
        self.add_widget(scroll)
```

but it's giving me an error saying:-

```
File "C:\Users\Himanshu Pharawal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 802, in run
     root = self.build()    File "main.py", line 47, in build
     return MainScreen()    File "main.py", line 38, in __init__
     entry = Entry(name='Facebook', date='30/21/2', size=(Window.width, sp(100)))    File "main.py", line 21, in __init__
     super(Entry, self).__init__(*args, **kargs)    File "C:\Users\Himanshu Pharawal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\relativelayout.py", line 265, in __init__
     super(RelativeLayout, self).__init__(**kw)    File "C:\Users\Himanshu Pharawal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\floatlayout.py", line 65, in __init__
     super(FloatLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)    File "C:\Users\Himanshu Pharawal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\layout.py", line 76, in __init__
     super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)    File "C:\Users\Himanshu Pharawal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 337, in __init__
     super(Widget, self).__init__(**kwargs)    File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 254, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__init__ (kivy\_event.c:5332) TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not indicate that you have a class called `Entry` that inherits from `FloatLayout` in the .py, and another `Entry` that inherits from `Widget` in the .kv, in the first place it will not obviate the Entry created in the .kv, what you must do is only indicate that you are going to continue to implement the class through `<Entry>` without anything else in the .kv.

On the other hand, the name and date properties are not automatically identified, what you must do is separate them as shown below:

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.core.window import Window

from kivy.metrics import sp

from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

class Mypopup(Popup):
    pass

class Entry(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, name="", date="", **kwargs):
        super(Entry, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = name
        self.date = date

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        super(Entry, self).on_touch_down(touch)
        popup = Mypopup()
        popup.open()
        return True

class MainScreen(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kargs)
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
        for i in range(100):
            entry = Entry(name='Facebook', date='30/21/2', size=(Window.width, sp(100)))
            layout.add_widget(entry)    
        scroll = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), height=Window.height)
        scroll.add_widget(layout)
        self.add_widget(scroll)

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

test.kv:

```
<Entry>:
    name: ''
    date: ''
    size_hint: (None, None)
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, .4
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
    Label:
        text: root.name[0:1]
        color: 41/255, 128/255, 185/255, 1
        pos: root.pos
        font_size: sp(50)
    Label:
        text: root.name[1:]
        color: 41/255, 128/255, 185/255, 1
        pos: root.x+sp(80), root.y+sp(8)
        font_size: sp(30)
    Label:
        text: root.date
        color: 17/255, 80/255, 122/255, 1
        pos: root.x+sp(50), root.y-sp(10)
        font_size: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution to error

The solution to solving that error is to define two *StringProperty* variables, *name* and *date* in class *Entry* in main.py.

## Override on_touch_down method

By default, touch events are dispatched to all currently displayed widgets. Therefore, we need to check whether the touch falls inside of `Entry` widget before instantiating and open `Mypopup`.

### Snippets

```
class Entry(RelativeLayout):
    name = StringProperty()
    date = StringProperty()

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            popup = Mypopup()
            popup.open()
            return True
        return super(Entry, self).on_touch_down(touch)
```

If the touch falls inside of our widget, we iinstantiate and open `Mypopup`, and return True, indicating that we have consumed the touch and don’t want it to propagate any further.

Finally, if the touch falls outside our widget, we call the original event using `super(…)` and return the result. This allows the touch event propagation to continue as it would normally have occurred.

[Programming Guide » Input management » Touch event basics](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/inputs.html#touch-event-basics)

> By default, touch events are dispatched to all currently displayed
>   widgets. This means widgets receive the touch event whether it occurs
>   within their physical area or not. ...
>  In order to provide the
>   maximum flexibility, Kivy dispatches the events to all the widgets and
>   lets them decide how to react to them. If you only want to respond to
>   touch events inside the widget, you simply check:
>
> ```
> def on_touch_down(self, touch):
>     if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
>         # The touch has occurred inside the widgets area. Do stuff!
>         pass
> ```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.metrics import sp
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


class Mypopup(Popup):
    pass


class Entry(RelativeLayout):
    name = StringProperty()
    date = StringProperty()

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            popup = Mypopup()
            popup.open()
            return True
        return super(Entry, self).on_touch_down(touch)


class MainScreen(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kargs)
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
        for i in range(100):
            entry = Entry(name='Facebook', date='30/21/2', size=(Window.width, sp(100)))
            layout.add_widget(entry)
        scroll = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), height=Window.height)
        scroll.add_widget(layout)
        self.add_widget(scroll)


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<Mypopup>:
    title: 'Test popup'
    size_hint: (None, None)
    size: (400, 400)
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'Hello world'

<Entry@Widget>:
    name: ''
    date: ''
    size_hint: (None, None)
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, .4
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
    Label:
        text: root.name[0:1]
        color: 41/255, 128/255, 185/255, 1
        pos: root.pos
        font_size: sp(50)
    Label:
        text: root.name[1:]
        color: 41/255, 128/255, 185/255, 1
        pos: root.x+sp(80), root.y+sp(8)
        font_size: sp(30)
    Label:
        text: root.date
        color: 17/255, 80/255, 122/255, 1
        pos: root.x+sp(50), root.y-sp(10)
        font_size: 10
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - App Startup]
[image: Img02 - Mypopup open]